# DefaultAppPool getting stopped after deploying ASP.NET MVC site on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After deploying my ASP.NET MVC application using AWS Extension for Visual Studio on Elastic Beanstalk application environment, it is showing `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

When I investigated it using Remote Desktop, I found that DefaultAppPool is getting stopped. I removed Automatic Shutdown on Fail setting for Pool but after that it was throwing `HTTP 403 forbidden` error. I am new to Elastic Beanstalk. So can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. For anyone facing the same issue just check the Event Viewer in Windows for any errors.

For my issue, I found that `System.Net.Http` was not copied to the `bin` directory because I upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8 from 4.6.1. In .NET Framework 4.8 I think this library is deprecated (correct me if I am wrong I am not sure but found this written somewhere on the Internet.). So, I downgraded the application to 4.6.1 and published it again. And it worked.

Hope this helps. :)